# 30 amp rv receptacle installation

Tags: electrical

I need to install a 30 amp 120v rv receptacle.  this is temporary.  I have in place 10/3 wire with ground.  can I use this wire with a 30amp single pole breaker in the panel and the rv receptacle on the other end?  if so, how should I treat the extra wire?

Answer (score 4):

Your RV plug is a TT30.    The 10/3 NM "Romex" building cable is sufficient to the task provided it is not exposed to weather.  If exposed to wet or weather, you just need a different category of cable for the exposed run.

You can use this with a 30A breaker, either single pole or double pole.  In either case you land the in-use hot wire (black preferred, red will also suffice) on one of the breaker poles.

The other hot wire, cap it off on both ends: put a wire-nut on it (probably yellow), tape that nut on (nuts don't like to stay on single wires), and tuck it back.

If  you ever have call to fit a NEMA 14-30 receptacle out there (say, for a larger RV, which uses **L14**-30), it's now an easy job.

You could also **fit the NEMA L14-30R today** by using a 2-pole breaker and both hots -- then [this $20 adapter cable](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Tasco-Locking-30-Amp-Plug-L14-30P-to-Right-Angle-30-Amp-Receptacle-TT-30R-RV-Adapter-16-00526HD/302621869).  This is safe because it's a 30A-30A adapter, so properly breakered.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer Harper - future proofing info too.

Answer (score 1):

A single pole 30A breaker is what you need for a 120v receptacle.  The extra wire should just be capped on both ends and will not be used.